# Software method to unplug/re-plug a DisplayPort cable to re-initialise the connection?

Tags: display, gpu, display-manager, displayport

Is there any software way to have the same effect as unplugging/re-plugging a DisplayPort cable without physically doing so?

The reason why I want to know is that my Dell monitor's resolution becomes 640*480 (native resolution is not found) and its name becomes "Unknown display" after waking up from sleep in multi-monitor settings with different physical resolutions. The only two ways I have found that restore the monitor are:

1. Unplug the monitor's power cable, wait till the light is gone from its button, and then plug it again so that the monitor sort-of reboots showing the Dell logo
2. Unplug the DisplayPort cable from the back of the GPU, and then plug it again.

But doing either of the two physically is cumbersome. Since I guess the (2) is probably telling the GPU to re-initialise the DP connection to the monitor, I thought that it might be possible to do that in software.

---

If it's relevant, my kernel version is 6.3.9, and I am using Wayland Gnome. It does not work to enable/disable the monitor in Gnome Settings -> Displays.

Answer (score 0):

I would look into the man page of xrandr.

```
xrandr --setmonitor
```

looks very promising.